# A simple Parametric Bootstrap on a Linear Model

Tags: p-value, bootstrap

My model: $y_t=\beta_1+\beta_2x_{2t}+\beta_3x_{3t}+u_t$, with $u_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

My sample is of size 50.

I'm trying to do a parametric bootstrap for the t-statistic of $\beta_3$, and
I'm certain that the t-statistic is 2.349, and the respective p-value (for 47 df) is 0.0231

Since the t-distribution is symmetric around zero, i.e. $F(-x)=1-F(x)$, there are several ways to compute an approximate p-value. The one I'm using is

$$\hat p(t_{\beta_3})=2\times\frac{\sum_{i=1}^B I(t_{i}^*<-|t_{\beta_3}|)}{B}$$ where $B$ is number of bootstrap samples I generate under OLS estimates for the coeeficients of the model above, with an estimate of the variance calculated from $SSR/47$.

Below you'll find the program I'm trying to create to obtain an approximate p-value of for the t-statistic

```
bootstrap[ts_, B_] := Module[{counter, tsboot, ctsboot},
    counter = 1; ctsboot = 0;
    beta = lm["BestFitParameters"];
    s2 = lm["EstimatedVariance"];
    While[counter <= B,
      resboot = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, s2], 50];
      yboot = Transpose[ToExpression[{x1, x2, x3}]].beta + resboot;
      lmboot = LinearModelFit[Transpose[ToExpression[{x2, x3, yboot}]],{w2,w3}, {w2, w3}];
      tsboot = lmboot["ParameterTStatistics"][[3]];
   (*Print["tsboot = ", tsboot, " and ts = ",ts];*)
      If[tsboot <- Abs[ts],(*If I remove the absolute values, I get similar results*)
      ctsboot++;
    ];
   counter++;
   ];
  ctsboot/B
  ]
```

To call the programme I do `bootstrap[lm["ParameterTStatistics"][[3]], B]`, where `lm["ParameterTStatistics"][[3]]=2.349` which is $t_{\beta_3}$, and $B \in \{99,999,9999\}$
The problem with my program is that the p-value computed is $0$, even for $B=9999$. Searching CV, I thought I might be creating incorrectly the bootstrap samples, but I don't see how...

I've confirmed that 'yboot', the bootstrap sample, is always different with each iteration. If for the formula of the p-value, I use $2\times\frac{\sum_{i=1}^B I(t_{i}^*>|t_{\beta_3}|)}{B}$, I get a p-value of around 0.6, for several different $B$ values

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas are "almost" correct. First of all, if you are interested in the 2-sided hypothesis, I would recommend the following formula (rather than the two formulas you proposed):

$$ \hat{p}_{boot} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^B I(|t_{i}^*|>|t_{\beta_3}|)}{B}$$

Now, why did I say that your formulas are "almost" correct? They would be correct, if you were correctly constructing your bootstrap estimated $t_{i}^*$, but your resampling is incorrect!

Bootstrap hypothesis testing is a bit more nuanced than bootstrapping for confidence intervals, standard errors, etc. In particular, you need to *simulate from your null hypothesis* [1]. In your case, this means that you should be simulating from:

$$y_t=\beta_1^*+\beta_2^* x_{2t}+ u_t$$

rather than from:

$$y_t=\beta_1^*+\beta_2^* x_{2t}+ \beta_3^* x_{3t} + u_t$$

<sub>[1] Alternatively, you could continue simulating as you do, but then you would need to calculate p-values by inverting the confidence intervals.</sub>

Comment: Plus 1, 'air' ;)

Comment: Air, by the way, do you know of a paper/bibliography that prove why the bootstrap works, and why it's better than most asymptotic tests (t, F, etc.),  in certain situations?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea That's a tough question, especially since bootstrap hypothesis tests are not as well studied as other bootstrap procedures. In general, theory for the bootstrap can be very mathematical, especially when one wants to show that it "works" better in a sense. People usually revert to higher order asymptotics to do that, I think some standard references are the book by Enno Mammen "When does bootstrap work" and the book by Peter Hall "The boostrap and edgeworth expansion". I have not read either of these books.

Comment: If instead of theory, you are more interested in intuition, then I think you cannot go wrong by reading Efron's (who of course was the one that introduced the bootstrap with his seminal paper in 1979) and Tibshirani's "Introduction to the bootstrap". Some people also like the bootstrap book by Davison.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of 'air' user, here's the code that seems to be working.

```
bootstrap[ts_, B_] := Module[{counter, tsboot, ctsboot},
  counter = 1; ctsboot = 0;
  x1 = ToExpression[x1];
  x2 = ToExpression[x2];
  x3 = ToExpression[x3];
  y = ToExpression[y];

  (*under the Null the model has beta_ 3 = 0 *)
  X2 = Transpose[{x1, x2}];
  lmnull = LinearModelFit[Transpose[{x2, y}], {w2}, {w2}];
  beta = lmnull["BestFitParameters"][[1 ;; 2]];
  s2 = lmnull["EstimatedVariance"];

  While[counter <= B,
   resboot = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, s2], 50];
   yboot = X2.beta + resboot;

   (*The bootstrap statistic is calculated for the unrestricted model \
but with yboot*)
   lmboot = 
    LinearModelFit[Transpose[{x2, x3, yboot}], {w2, w3}, {w2, w3}];
   tsboot = lmboot["ParameterTStatistics"][[3]];

   If[tsboot > Abs[ts],
    ctsboot++;
    ];
   counter++;
   ];
  2*ctsboot/B
  ]
```